# How do I make a single Application run on different JVMs?

Tags: java

I want to make a single java application run on more than one  JVM simultaneously. How do I do this?

Comment: To read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq ;-)

Comment: `to be or not to be` What is the question?

Comment: Sorry you need to be very more precise on the problem you are facing

Comment: If you want to use one JVM or more, You should ask yourself; Will this make things simpler or more complicated? I suggest using the simpler solution whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Java VM is typically just an application on your system; for instance, `java.exe` on Windows. If you want to run more than one JVM, just run more than one copy of `java.exe`. You can run as many copies simultaneously as you'd like.